# Is "stress test" hyphenated when an adjective?

Tags: hyphenation

My question is when "stress test" is an adjective is it hyphenated?

Comment: Please give an example of stress test as an adjective.

Comment: If you mean in something like "a stress-test monitor", then yes.

Comment: Yes, you'd use a hyphen between them.

Comment: stress tested solutions.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want to use it before the noun because how else would it become an adjective?

> Use a hyphen in a compound modifier when the modifier comes before the word it’s modifying.

However,

> Generally, you need the hyphen only if the two words are functioning together as an adjective before the noun they’re describing. If the noun comes first, leave the hyphen out.

source: https://www.grammarly.com/blog/hyphen/